# How can I match the shortest possible sequence of characters that satisfy my regex pattern?

Tags: regex, perl, matching

I've a string `"ajjjjjjjjjaab"`

I want a pattern which will match the last `"ab"` and not the whole string or even `"aab"`.

```
/a.*?b/  # returns two groups
```

or

```
/a.??b/ # matches last aab
```

Neither works.

Comment: I've added an answer, assuming you want the **last** match, and optional characters between `a` and `b` (That is, not the pattern `ab`). Either way, you can add a lot of details to the question, like a few examples.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way around your problem is to match:

```
.*(a.*b)
```

With the first `.*` being greedy, it matches as much as it can. Then you get a captured group with the match you really need, (`$1`). Note that this assumes you're matching the last occurrence of the pattern. You may want `.*(a.*?b)` if you have multiple `b`s near the end of the string, and you want the first one after the last `a`.

Comment: Isn't there any specific pattern for this?

Comment: @user - not that I'm aware of. .Net can match right-to-left, or you can always reverse the string and match `b.*?a`. You can also try something like `a((?!a).)*b` (or `a[^a]*b`), but it can get messy with a complex pattern - I *assume* you need a little more than `a` and `b`...

Comment: this *is* the specific pattern for this.

Answer (score 5):

One of:

```
/a[^a]*b/
/a[^ab]*b/
```

---

If `a` and `b` are actually more complex patterns, one can use the following:

```
/a(?:(?!a).)*b/s
/a(?:(?!a|b).)*b/s
```

---

If `a` and `b` represent long/complex patterns, one can avoid repeating them using variables like in any other code.

```
my $re1 = qr/a/;
my $re2 = qr/b/;

/$re1(?:(?!$re1|$re2).)*$re2/s
```

One can also use subpatterns.

```
/
   (?&A) (?:(?!(?&A)|(?&B)).)* (?&B)

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<A> a )
      (?<B> b )
   )
/xs
```

Comment: while it's a perfectly correct answer, it's the least interesting

Comment: @user713303, In fact, it's the only correct answer. You shouldn't use the non-greediness modifier as anything other than as a performance hint. To do otherwise is a fragile and error prone hack. // Is the issue that you need an explanation? the first two are quite self-explanatory given the context, and the last two are version of the first two that work if `a` and `b` are actually longer than one character.

Comment: I really hate that you need to repeat `a` (or both `a` and `b`) twice. And the latter two regexes look way too complex for such a trivial task

Comment: @user713303, it's unfortunate,  but required

Comment: That said, if the thing being repeated is long and complex, variables can be used as anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern matching in Perl is Left Most, Longest* by default. Using `??`, `*?`, or `+?` will change that portion to Left Most, Shortest, but Left Most still takes precedence.

There is a way to get Perl to match Right Most, which might get you your desired effect, but it will also confuse the hell out of the next person to read your code, so use it with care.

The basic idea is to reverse everything related to the pattern match, so right becomes left.

```
my $subject = 'ajjjjjjjjjaab';
my $rev_sub = reverse $subject; # reverse the string being matched.
my $result;
if ($rev_sub =~ /(b.*?a)/) {    # reverse the pattern to match.
    $result = reverse $1;       # reverse the results of the match.
}
print $result;
```

The solutions provided by ikegami and Kobi both find similar results for your example. Depending on your real patterns and strings you might find very different performance for each method. Always [`Benchmark`](http://p3rl.org/Benchmark) based off your real needs.

*Longest only for the immediate token being matched, excluding alternations which are tried in order left to right, etc.

Comment: Note: That approach fails for `a...a...b...b`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but then use just `/ab/` for matching and you go it. Or `/a{1}b/`. Or?